# Mqtt back end over websocket

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

We have an Mqtt broker in the back-end which is setup to accept connections over WebSocket. Everything works when I connect directly to this machine. But we would like to route all calls through Enterprise integrator. I can't seem to get this working correctly. The backend websocket listens on a path, not on the root (eg: machine:9999/api/mqtt). For testing purposes the back-end Mqtt broker has no security implemented. It accepts every connection and all can subscribe and publish.

Changes to axis.xml

```
<transportReceiver name="mqtt" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mqtt.MqttListener">
    <parameter locked="false" name="mqttConFactory">
        <parameter locked="false" name="mqtt.server.host.name">workerv2</parameter>
        <parameter name="mqtt.connection.factory">mqttConFactory</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="mqtt.server.port">9026</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="mqtt.client.id">client-id-1234</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="mqtt.topic.name">esb.test</parameter>
    </parameter>
</transportReceiver>

<transportSender name="ws" class="org.wso2.carbon.websocket.transport.WebsocketTransportSender">
    <parameter name="ws.outflow.dispatch.sequence" locked="false">outflowDispatchSeq</parameter>
    <parameter name="ws.outflow.dispatch.fault.sequence" locked="false">outflowFaultSeq</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

I've copied the jar file into the libs folder: org.exlipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.0.jar

I've setup my sequences and websocket inbound endpoint as per the example [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/WSO2EI/Sending+a+Message+from+a+WebSocket+Client+to+a+WebSocket+Endpoint#SendingaMessagefromaWebSocketClienttoaWebSocketEndpoint-Prerequisites)

I don't know how to troubleshoot this, I have log4j set to show wire logs but can't seem to get any information from them. I don't see any errors, so I think I have to be close(?)

Can you help me please?

EDIT

I managed to setup the websocket to websocket connection. When connecting directly the websocket works and I can connect successfully. But when I connect through the wso2ei, I can see the log message and everything looks ok. But all requests time out after 120 seconds. I can't seem to debug headers for websockets. Any help would be appreciated.

As per example my dispatch sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="dispatchSeq" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="full">
        <property name="LOGGED_MESSAGE" value="LOGGED"/>
    </log>
    <send>
        <endpoint>
            <address uri="ws://10.100.14.8:9026/api/v2/mqtt"/>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

My out sequence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="outDispatchSeq" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="full"/>
    <respond/>
</sequence>
```

My inbound endpoint

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><inboundEndpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="testMQTT" sequence="dispatchSeq" onError="fault" protocol="ws" suspend="false">
<parameters>
    <parameter name="inbound.ws.port">9091</parameter>
    <parameter name="ws.client.side.broadcast.level">0</parameter>
    <parameter name="ws.outflow.dispatch.sequence">outDispatchSeq</parameter>
    <parameter name="ws.outflow.dispatch.fault.sequence">fault</parameter>
    <parameter name="ws.use.port.offset">false</parameter>
</parameters>
```

Log messages

```
TID: [-1] [] [2018-04-24 14:25:14,675]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: , MessageID: urn:uuid:decebbbe-8ad7-4174-adb9-1bc324764275, Direction: request, LOGGED_MESSAGE = LOGGED, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-04-24 14:25:16,177]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler} -  Expiring message ID : urn:uuid:26b39fa8-9b5e-44cd-86b3-caa72c30047b; dropping message after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT of : 120 seconds for AnonymousEndpoint, URI : ws://10.100.14.8:9026/api/v2/mqtt, Received through Inbound Endpoint : testMQTT {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler}
```

Comment: Hi, check the OutSeq.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="outDispatchSeq" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <log level="full"/><send/>
</sequence>

Comment: @JuanPablo the log mediator was never called, I changed it. But no change noticable in logs.

Comment: I can see the the log message going out so the out sequence is called. But none of the wire logs are showing. How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: @JuanPablo thank you, but this gives the following error: TID: [-1] [] [2018-04-24 15:43:24,174] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils} -  Address information does not exist in the Endpoint Reference (EPR).The system cannot infer the transport mechanism. {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-04-24 15:43:24,174] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  Unexpected error during sending message out {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Address information does not exist in the Endpoint Reference (EPR).

Comment: I found out this works for some clients. I'm missing some headers for other clients. For instance header Sec-WebSocket-Protocol is not returned. I tried changing the passthrough config to include the header but it gets stripped, even if I set it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked arount the problem, websocket connects directly without the esb integrator.